# How to insert binary data into sqlite3 database in bash?

Tags: sql, bash, sqlite, binary

I want to insert binary data(png,jpg,gif,etc) into a sqlite3 database within a bash script.
I use the standalone binary `sqlite3`. How can I write the SQL statement?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure that command-line tool will let you insert arbitrary data like that.  You could base64 encode the data first, I guess.

Comment: stupid workaround via python, to write a sqlite3 blob to stdout: `python -c "import sys, sqlite3; sys.stdout.buffer.write(sqlite3.connect(sys.argv[1]).execute('select some_blob_column from some_table limit 1').fetchone()[0])" some_sqlite_database.db` ... inserting a blob via python would be similar ; ) but this is stupid, because its slow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. The file `test.jpg` is inserted in the table `foo` of the database `foodb` after being `hexdump`ed to the binary literal format of sqlite:

```
[someone@somewhere tmp]$ sqlite3 foodb "create table foo (bar blob);"
[someone@somewhere tmp]$ echo "insert into foo values (X'`hexdump -ve '1/1 "%.2x"' test.jpg`');" | sqlite3 foodb
```

**EDIT**

And here we see that the data is store in "full-fidelity" as the .jpg file can be restored:

```
[somneone@somewhere tmp]$ sqlite3 foodb "select quote(bar) from foo;" | perl -ne 's/([0-9a-f]{2})/print chr hex $1/gie' > bla.jpg 
[somneone@somewhere tmp]$ ll *.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 someone someone 618441 Apr 28 16:59 bla.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 someone someone 618441 Apr 28 16:37 test.jpg
[someone@somewhere tmp]$ md5sum *.jpg 
3237a2b76050f2780c592455b3414813  bla.jpg
3237a2b76050f2780c592455b3414813  test.jpg
```

Furthermore, this approach is space efficient as it store the .jpg using sqlite's BLOB type. It doesn't stringify the image using for example base64 encoding.

```
[someone@somewhere tmp]$ ll foodb 
-rw-r--r-- 1 someone someone 622592 Apr 28 16:37 foodb
```

Comment: This won't work :( I know it won't work, because I was going to post it 20 minutes ago, but can't get some test cases to work. Specifically, if you query that column, the results will be truncated at the first 0x00 (in jpeg, you're almost guaranteed to have a NULL byte somewhere). If you select `quote(bar)` it will give you the original x'...'

Comment: @DavidSouther: ain't it normal to have 0x00 in binary data??? please go read about the BLOB type of sqlite. What you are expecting is data stored in some human-readable format which is way less space efficient; the OP makes no such requirement.

Comment: It is a very normal thing. I am expecting, and indeed am correct in that sqlite correctly stores 0x00 in a blob column. The problem is when you run a `select` on that column- the `select` will only return up to the first 0x00. That is the problem I was pointing out, and the fix is what we included in our edits by using `select quote()` and converting that hex back to the binary output.

Comment: I like your edits :) Now the only thing I can claim is that xxd is shorter than your perl command! Once again, we see the power of the Unix way.

Comment: @DavidSouther: I'd just like to point out that the OP asks about inserting.

Comment: Sure. Inserting is great, but if someone doesn't know how to do this insert, they will be very surprised about the results of their `select`. Remembering that `quote` exists, much less realizing you need to use it is not a trivial undertaking.

Comment: @kev: As a replacement for hexdump?

Comment: Note that this approach will fail if the output of `hexdump` is larger than `131000`

Answer (score 10):

As I mentioned in the comment on @sixfeetsix's answer, inserting the data is only half the problem. Once it's in, you'll need to get it back out. We can use xxd for this.

```
#A nice hubble image to work with.
echo 'http://asd.gsfc.nasa.gov/archive/hubble/Hubble_20th.jpg' > imageurl.txt
image=imageurl.txt
curl $image > image.jpg

#Insert the image, using hexdump to read the data into SQLite's BLOB literal syntax.
echo "create table images (image blob);" | sqlite3 images.db
echo "insert into images (image) values(x'$(hexdump -ve '1/1 "%0.2X"' image.jpg)');" | sqlite3 images.db 2>&1

#Select just the one image, then use xxd to convert from hex back to binary.
echo "select quote(image) from images limit 1 offset 0;" | sqlite3 images.db  | tr -d "X'" | xxd -r -p > newimage.jpg
eog newimage.jpg
```